# How to parse twitch IRC emotes in Swift?

Tags: swift, twitch

I'm trying to parse Twitch IRC emotes and extract it from a string. Twitch IRC message provides a range which is a location of an emote in a string. Example:

> string="Kappa abcdef"; range start=0; range end=4

means emote Kappa is located from the index 0 to 4 in the string "Kappa abcdef".

Here's my function that will return an emote based on the range:

```
func extractEmoteName(from message: String, rangeStart: Int, rangeEnd: Int) -> String? {
    guard
        let indexStart = message.index(message.startIndex, offsetBy: rangeStart, limitedBy: message.endIndex),
        let limitIndex = message.index(message.endIndex, offsetBy: -1, limitedBy: message.startIndex),
        let indexEnd = message.index(message.startIndex, offsetBy: rangeEnd, limitedBy: limitIndex)
    else {
        print("out of bounds")
        return nil
    }
    
    return String(message[indexStart ... indexEnd])
}
```

Using this on the example string: `extractEmoteName(from: "Kappa abcdef", rangeStart: 0, rangeEnd: 4)` will return `Kappa` as a result.

I'm having a trouble with the strings that contain emojis with multiple unicode scalars:

> string="⚠️ Kappa"; range start=3; range end=7

Result of the extraction function is `nil`:

```
extractEmoteName(from: "⚠️ Kappa", rangeStart: 3, rangeEnd: 7) // prints "out of bounds"
```

At the same time, messages with the single scalar emotes parses fine because the range provided by Twitch is different:

> string=" Kappa"; range start=2; range end=6

```
extractEmoteName(from: " Kappa", rangeStart: 2, rangeEnd: 6) // returns "Kappa"
```

What should be changed in `extractEmoteName` to make it work with all emoji characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `unicodeScalars`, it will represent the string in unicode scalars:
​

```
func extractEmoteName(from input: String, rangeStart: Int, rangeEnd: Int) -> String? {
    let message = input.unicodeScalars
    
    guard
        let indexStart = message.index(message.startIndex, offsetBy: rangeStart, limitedBy: message.endIndex),
        let limitIndex = message.index(message.endIndex, offsetBy: -1, limitedBy: message.startIndex),
        let indexEnd = message.index(message.startIndex, offsetBy: rangeEnd, limitedBy: limitIndex)
    else {
        print("out of bounds")
        return nil
    }
    
    return String(message[indexStart ... indexEnd])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by counting scalars.

```swift
func extractEmoteName(from message: String, rangeStart: Int, rangeEnd: Int) -> String? {
    guard rangeStart >= 0 && rangeStart <= rangeEnd else {
        return nil
    }
    let scalars = message.unicodeScalars
    let start = scalars.index(scalars.startIndex, offsetBy: rangeStart)
    let end = scalars.index(scalars.startIndex, offsetBy: rangeEnd)
    let nameScalars = scalars[start...end]
    return String(nameScalars)
}
```